# I am no longer able to read sd card

Tags: external-sd

i saved pictures and text messages to external sd card. Why cant i read them? I have tried several apps but no luck, just garbled gibberish, help please!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the SD card is mounted. If it was somehow unmounted this could happen. This option will be in Settings > Storage  scroll down to SD card. Make sure that it indicates that the SD card is mounted or at least doesn't say "Insert SD Card".

If it is mounted, unmount it, take it out, put it back in, and see if anything changes. If it isn't recognized, then just take it out and put it back in. Check back in with the details on how that goes.